# minipage show up in the top of the page

Tags: minipage

When I add a minipage that includes a list and picture side by side, they show up in the top of the page. In the tex file however I have mentioned that minipage has to be right after the text. The following picture is before adding a minipage.

[image]

After adding the minipage :

```
\section*{Matériels utilisés}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*)]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*)]
\item efdff
\item fdfdf
\item dfdf 
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../Materiel-proctor.PNG} 
\caption{dffd}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

look how it appears

[image]

If someone knows the problem, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You included the minipages inside of a `figure` environment which itself is a floating environment. This means it does not necessarily show up where you defined it in your code. If you don't want your image to float, do not use the `figure` environment and replace the `\caption{...}` command with `\captionof{figure}{...}` and add the `caption` package to your preamble.

Comment: `minipage` is just like a big letter, it is never moved by latex, but you have wrapped that in `figure` the only thing `figure` does is allow the text to be moved. perhaps `\begin{figure}[htpb]` then it might be placed at that point, but will still be moved if it doesn't fit.